# Analog of '& in cshell' in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I was using & in cshell in the end of a command, in order to execute the command as an independent process from the terminal:

```
kate filename.txt&
```

How I should do this in bash?

Answer (score 4):

The same way.  From `bash(1)`:

> ```
>  If  a  command  is terminated by the control operator &, the shell exe-
>  cutes the command in the background in a subshell.  The shell does  not
>  wait  for  the command to finish, and the return status is 0.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Using & will background the job, but it is still tied to the shell.

The difference you may find between csh and bash with & is with regard to redirecting STDERR.

In csh:

```
    kate filename.txt >& kateout.log
```

In bash:

```
    kate filename.txt > kateout.log 2>&1
```

If you want the process to survive the parent shell/terminal closing, try "nohup" i.e.:

```
    nohup kate filename.txt > kateout.log 2>&1
```

The redirect is optional; if there is output it will go to nohup.out in the current working directory.